# Request timing out only on iPad, working fine on laptops and desktops

Tags: php, ios, macos, laravel, ipad

I have a Laravel 5.1 web app that is posting and requesting fairly large amounts of data. I currently have my max_execution_time set to 300 in my php.ini file, and it is working great on laptops. However, when I try to access the page from an iPad pro I get the following response:

```
Safari could not open the page because the server stopped responding.
```

It times out at exactly 1 minute. I am running a LEMP stack on Ubuntu 14.04 and this problem only seems to be when trying to access the site on an iPad. Any thoughts as to how to resolve this?

Comment: have you cleared your safari settings to see if its a device issue?

Comment: Yes, that didn't seem to do anything. It still timed out at exactly 60 seconds.

Comment: how about limiting your data set to see if you will even receive a response?

Answer (score 0):

This is not the solution but you can check for your site is down for all?

[DownForEveryoneOrJustMe.com](http://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/), type your url and check it.

Before it once check after clear browser cache. Further you can monitor downtime issue with [Pingdom](http://pingdom.com/)

May this will help you!